# Javascript random color for all class same color

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have JavaScript that will pick between two colors to change the classes colors but it is changing them to different colors of each other. So the `.navbar` will be purple when the `.alert` is in blue I need it to pick a color but make sure they are both the same color.

```
var colors = ['#2196F3','#8A229C'];
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-default, .alert-info');

for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    // Pick a random color from the array 'colors'.
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `Math.random` function out of the loop & get the random number only once

```
var colors = ['#2196F3', '#8A229C'];
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-default, .alert-info');
// random number will be generated only once
var getColor =Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[getColor];
}
```